# Usage of 'fit' as tight

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context

In Indian languages I have seen the usage of the word 'fit' as being used to imply something is too-tight. In a Gujarati the sentence would use the word 'fit' to describe a garment that is too tight when worn. "Its too 'fit'  when I wear it" (spoken in a local language with 'fit' as the only English word).

I didn't think too much of this and dismissed it as an Indianism till I realized this word is used in the exact same way in Thai to describe the exact same thing.

This made me curious as to how in 2 similar but distant and different cultures a foreign word would get used to mean the exact same thing, while neither the local languages have this word nor does the word in the language of origin have this meaning.

(Reference for the Thai usage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3CyGvdky50&t=418s )

Comment: Probably from the English usage of tight-fit.

Comment: ...or [***close-fit**ting*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22close-fit+clothes%22)